# Reason for error: var might not have been initiazed

Tags: java

The user should enter the values to x and y, and if x is greater than 5 and and when y= 0 , then z should be equivalent to x+y. However, when I compile it gives me an error saying that z might not have been initialized.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class add {
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a value for x");
        int x = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEnter a value for y ");
        int y = input.nextInt();

        int z;

        if (x > 5){
            if (y == 0)
                z = x + y;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + z);

        }
        else
            System.out.println("The answer is only" + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply: If `y == 0` is false then `z` will remain uninitialized.

Comment: ... or `x > 5` is false

Comment: You are initializing `z` only when `y==0`. You need to initialize if you want to use it further, like `int z = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not using braces for if condition, your z will not initialized.

To solve such kind problems always keep in mind that if you are calculating something with integer variable do initialize them with some value (here, 0 is the best).

Then you can access that variable anywhere in the code without any initialization error.

To rid of this problem, you have two ways

One way:

just simply initialize your z variable like:

```
int z=0;
```

Second way:

Try to put braces for if condition like:

```
if (y == 0){
    z = x + y;
    System.out.println("The answer is " + z);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an execution path where `z` doesn't get initialized, but you attempt to print it.  If `x` is greater than `5`, but `y` isn't `0`, then `z` is not initialized, but you refer to `z` when printing it.

Use braces to create an inner block for your inner `if` statement, so `z` is only referenced if it's initialized:

```
if (x > 5){
    if (y == 0) {
        z = x + y;
        System.out.println("The answer is " + z);
    }
}
```

Also, proper indenting helps to identify visually what's part of a block and what's not.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'if' statement is misleading:

```
if (y == 0)
  z = x + y;
```

What if y != 0? In that case, z is not initialized.

The next line

```
System.out.println("The answer is " + z);
```

doesn't apply to the y==0 statement, as you don't have braces {}.

You probably meant to write something like:

```
if (x > 5) {
  if (y == 0) {
    z = x + y;
    System.out.println("The answer is " + z);
  }
}
```

Note the "{" after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assure the compiler that `z` will get a value **no matter what**.

You may want to assign it a default value when declaring it.

Something along these lines:

```
int z = 0;  // just an example
```

Answer (score 0):

int z has no value, try the code at the bottom then give it a 0 or input.nextInt();
int z = 0;
or 
int z = input.nextInt();